# Enable Click action on both the forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two forms in one landing page. one is the popup form.

```
<form method="post" class="catalyst_form test-form" action="email.php" id="test-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email id *" required>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact number *" required
        pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" title="Enter 10 digit mobile number.">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City *" required>
    <select name="service" id="service" placeholder="Select Service *" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Company type</option>
        <option value="Pvt Ltd">Pvt Ltd</option>
        <option value="LLP">LLP</option>
        <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
        <option value="Sec 8 Company">Sec 8 Company</option>
        <option value="I am not sure about this
                ">I am not sure about this
        </option>
    </select>
    <div class="button_center">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="submit-form" class="filled-button">
    </div>
</form>
```

And a normal form

```
<form action="email.php" method="POST" id="new-form" class="test-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name *" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email id *" required>
    <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Contact number *" required
        pattern="[6789][0-9]{9}" title="Enter 10 digit mobile number.">
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City *" required>
    <select name="service" id="service" placeholder="Select Service *" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Company type</option>
        <option value="Pvt Ltd">Pvt Ltd</option>
        <option value="LLP">LLP</option>
        <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
        <option value="Sec 8 Company">Sec 8 Company</option>
        <option value="I am not sure about this
                ">I am not sure about this
        </option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" id="new-submit">
</form>
```

My JQuery Code is like this:

```
    <script>
        var $form = $('form#test-form')
        url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwS7PfJ-Olo0U7_ZEfulrQ5OZnLCnwcUEX6uRE23lvKZbfNoh1K/exec'
        $('#submit-form').on('click', function (e) {
            $('#submit-form').val("Please Wait...").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            e.preventDefault();
            var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $form.serialize()
            }).done(
                $.post('email.php', $('form#test-form').serialize()),
                window.location.replace("link to thank you page")
            );
        })
    </script>
```

I want to enable this script on both the forms. I have tried adding classes but my JS seems not work as expected. How should I select the form so that works on both the forms.

I even tried two scripts with different ID's which also didn't work.

My aim is two use this same script for both the forms.

Comment: first use `$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {...` if your from in popup and action not work, then use two function for ajax call. call second function on `success` of first ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a form submit event handler `this` is the form the event occurred on

So you can use that to get the serialized data for the specific form and use your common class for the selector.

You are also missing  callback functions for `done()` and `$.post`

```
var url ='...';
$('.test-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this),
       data = $form.serialize();// data from current form instance

  $form.find('input:submit').val("Please Wait...").prop('disabled', true);

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
  }).done(function(){
    $.post('email.php', data, function(){
        window.location.replace("link to thank you page")
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I am getting an error `2(index):810 Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Comment: I left that out since it wasn't relevant to the issue.....you still need to define that variable. See update also how to disable current button

Answer (score 0):

You can use following piece of code to enable that same callback function on both submit-buttons:

```
$('body').on('click', '#new-submit, #submit-form', function (e) {
   $('#submit-form').val("Please Wait...").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   ...
});
```

Comment: But need the specific instance data also. The selectors for event listener are only part of the issue